# Store content in android market

Tags: android

Can I upload content(any type png/jpg) onto android market, which I could download while the application is running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can only upload Application `.apk` files on to the Market.

If you don't have much content you can [embed it in your application as a `Resource`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/resources/resources-i18n.html).  The content is then embedded into the `.apk` file and you can retrieve it using a standard Android API.

If you have lot of content - say, many megabytes - which you would rather download and perhaps cache on the SD card you'll need your own website.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add it to `/res/drawable` and use it without the need of downloading.